# How to deploy Custom Label Translations

Tags: deployment, change-set, customlabel, translation

I have created about  80 custom labels and translated then to French.
After deploying the Custom Labels via salesforce change set to Production, I found the translations did not get deployed. Is there a way to deploy Custom Labels along with translations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to deploy Custom Label translations, it is necessary to include Language Translation to changeset.

Check the screenshot below:

[image]